# Javascript Postcode Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so, I'm currently working on a site that has a store finder and the store finder works great with both town names and post codes but the post code has to have a space in it. 
E.g. 'RG1 7UE' and won't work without the space E.g. 'RG17UE'

So i've got a bit of JS on the text box (see below) to adjust the spacing on the postcode and that works great, the only problem now is that the JS will put a space in if you type a town or city in the box.  Does anyone have an idea how i can get around this so that i can use the same text input box for both city and postcode?

Thanks,

Martyn

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a postcode or town/city..." value="<?php echo $_POST['text'] ?>"  id="address" name="text" class="locator_inputform px192 search-box" onblur="this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,'').replace( /^(.{2,4})(.{3})(.*)$/, '$1 $2' )">
```

Comment: My post code looks nothing like that. What is the specification for the post code that you want? It would be good to give users a hint about that too.

Answer (score 1):

Only do the replacement if there is a digit in the input.

```
if (/\d/.test(this.value)) {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/ /g,'')
    .replace( /^(.{2,4})(.{3})(.*)$/, '$1 $2' );
}
```

Works because postal codes always have a digit (right?), but cities will never have a number in their name.

---

But that said, this seems like a poor design. What kind of system is flexible enough to accept a post code or a city by the same input, but forces strict constraints around the format of the data? If it's that strict, it should accept the code on a discreet input.

Comment: Thanks for that it works great! In regards to the design, yeah i know it's kinda a long story.  Thanks for your help there though!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to do this, this works great! Thanks @AlexWayne

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Postcode or Street Name and/or Town..." value="<?php echo $_POST['text'] ?>"  id="address" name="name" onblur="if (/\d/.test(this.value)) {
this.value = this.value
.replace(/ /g,'')
.replace( /^(.{2,4})(.{3})(.*)$/, '$1 $2' );
}" >
```